How to search / filter historical SOL transfers / transactions via Web3.js?
I need to find a list of SOL transfers and a list of SPL Token transfers to a given address.
So far it seems there is no such API from Solana web3.js, except getSignaturesForAddress(), getParsedTransactions() offering close results.
But how can I filter out SOL transfers from SPL Token transfers?
By observing detail variable below, it seems the only difference is:

SOL transfers have smaller detail data
SOL transfers have only 3 instructions, but SPL Token transfers have 4 instructions
SOL transfers have only instruction.programId === ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 or 11111111111111111111111111111111
SOL transfer instruction.accounts values are only empty object or undefined, while in SPL transfers the 4th instruction has many addresses in the accounts object

const transactionDetails = await solanaConnection.getParsedTransactions(
  signatureList, {maxSupportedTransactionVersion:0});

transactionDetails.forEach((detail, index) => {
    log("detail:", detail)
    const transactionInstructions = txn?.transaction.message.instructions;
    transactionInstructions?.forEach((instruction, n)=>{
        log(`${n} programId: ${instruction.programId.toString()}`);
        log(`${n} accounts: ${instruction.accounts}`);//undefined or object
        if(!isEmptyObj(instruction.accounts)) log("==>> Token Detected!")
    })
})

What is the best solution?
Is checking instruction.accounts value approach the correct approach?

After fetching transactions, it may be easier to look at the balances fields, ie. preTokenBalances / postTokenBalances and preBalances / postBalances.
https://solana.com/docs/rpc/http/gettransaction#result has more info about the returned object from getTransaction
That way you don't need to worry about instructions, but rather the final result of the transaction.
